# how to consume/pull artifacts from Nexus Staging repository without closing it in maven build

Tags: maven-3, nexus, staging

Our Maven Build in CI is split into different steps each one run in a different Jenkins work-space and build server
Example: Module A runs on Server1 , Module B runs on Server2,

Module B depends on Module A artifacts, while working with Nexus Staging plugin to deploy artifacts Module B is failing to download artifact dependencies of Module A.

Is there way to pull/consume/download artifacts from Staging repository without closing it (can't close repository after Module A build as we would like to have all artifacts staged to one repository) ?

Comment: found that there is no such option in staging.